# Premailer/inline css using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, css, phantomjs, premailer

We are aware of premailer which converts styling into inline css and also changes relative urls to absolute urls. There is an online version of it premailer.dialect.ca which provides the same.

I need to use this functionality ie given any url, I need to convert it into premailed version.
However I may have to use this may be thousands of times a day and hence I cant use premailer.dialect.ca api. There is a python-premailer which does the same but I couldnt find any documentation for converting html from given url to premailed version.

How can I achieve this using premailer.py or phantom.js or any other solution? Am I missing some thing? I assume it must take lot of time to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

dialectica.ca provides an API for this kind of premailer operations. It converts any html page..provided their url into inline css based html page.